# RegExp for matching three letters, but not text "BUY"

Tags: regex

I have two buttons on form, one of the buttons contain currency code (EUR, USD, GBP,CHF,..) and another one - trade direction (BUY or SELL). And some utility recognize buttons by it's text. 
To recognize button with currencies, I use Regular expression ":[A-Z]{3}", but it don't work properly when second button contain text "BUY" (regex description returns more than one object).

Question: how can I write pattern for Regular expression, which means: match only when text contain three upper letters, but not text "BUY"?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also try to just match the content of the first button only. That way you don't care if some third button `YAY` or `NAY` is added.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
^(?!BUY)[A-Z]{3}$
```

`(?!BUY)` is [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973609#2973609) that would fail if it matches the regex `BUY`

Answer (score 17):

You can use a negative look-behind assertion to verify that the text just matched does not equal *BUY*.

```
[A-Z]{3}(?<!BUY)
```

Comment: the look ahead version is more widely supported in different regex implementations, and has better performance (I think).

Comment: this worked for me in a (simulation) of java8 regex, while the accepted answer didn't