# replace semicolon (;) but not html characters (&nbsp; etc.)

Tags: php, javascript, regex, html-parsing, smarty

I'm looking for regexp for my issue.
I have a text (specification of a product), for example:

`length: 20cm; height: 10cm; &laquo;Night&raquo; mode: yes;&nbsp;manufacturer : Sony&copy; manual&nbsp;:&nbsp;yes`

The final result should look like this

```
<tr><td>length</td><td>20cm</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>manufacturer</td><td>Sony&copy;</td></tr>
```

So I should replace `":" + whitespace characters(\s*)` for `"</td><td>"`  and `";" + whitespace characters(\s*)` for `"</td></tr><tr><td>"`, but not in the case where there are  latin symbols `[a-z]+` and `&` sign before the `;`.
The point is in html chars like &_nbsp; &_laquo; &_copy etc. that contains ";"

In other words `:\s*` but not `&[a-z]+[;]`.

How can I do this?

My regexp in smarty looks like this:
" |regex_replace:"/[:]\s*/":""|regex_replace:"/[;]\s*/":"" " so the only thing is to remove html chars... I tried some combinations with (?!...) but no success
I'm looking for something like this
[RegExp for matching three letters, but not text "BUY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194867/regexp-for-matching-three-letters-but-not-text-buy)

Comment: Note that the `regex` tag also states: *Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$str = 'length: 20cm; height: 10cm; &laquo;Night&raquo; mode: yes;&nbsp;manufacturer : Sony&copy; manual&nbsp;:&nbsp;yes';
$str = preg_replace('#(?!&[a-z]+); #', '</td></tr><tr><td>', $str);
$str = preg_replace('#: #', '</td><td>', $str);
```

Comment: BTW very easy solution for smarty instead of using curly braces!

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look-behind to find semicolons *not* part of an encoded character:

```
(?<!&[a-z]{2})(?<!&[a-z]{3})(?<!&[a-z]{4})(?<!&[a-z]{5});\s*
```

This regex matches only naked semi colons. Unfortunately, the multiple look-behinds are required so cover all possibilities due to negative look behinds demanding a fixed length expression.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/1v60R4RZeP) of this regex.

Comment: could you write a whole version?

Comment: I believe It's working) But I have some trouble issue with a smarty parser... But it's not disallow your answer, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, although I swapped the `[a-z]` for `#[0-9]`, then you only need to do it for 2,3 and 4 lengths

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the **regular expression**, you can step like this:

1. remove all character, except `\w : ; &`
2. replace all `&copy;` to `@@@copy###`
3. you can replace the `: ;` with `<td>` now
4. replace all `@@@copy###` to `&copy;`
5. remove all `&nbsp;`

Comment: Actually my regexp in smarty looks like this " |regex_replace:"/[:]\s*/":"</td><td>"|regex_replace:"/[;]\s*/":"</td></tr><tr><td>" " so the only thing is to remove html chars...

Comment: step 2, you can replace all the `/&(\w){1,4});/` to the `@@@$1###` (javascript syntax)

Comment: But there are so many special characters... For example I've seen usage of &oslash; I believe it should be a way to skip a regexp, for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194867/regexp-for-matching-three-letters-but-not-text-buy

Comment: Negative lookahead is a little complicated and not supported well in some language. So I think the easiest way is to replace the html chars with some personal tag. Then replace them back;

Comment: Could you help me to write this thing? get word "&laquo;" ==> /&(\w){1,8});/  ==>  @@@laquo### as you proposed?

Comment: "&laquo;".replace(/&(\w{1,8});/g, "@@@$1###"); in JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for sharing you thoughts! I'll keep in mind it for other tasks!