# How to match strings containing special string, but not containing another string with REGEXMATCH

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

I have a working REGEXMATCH based formula

`=ArrayFormula(if( REGEXMATCH(topProdukte!AV2,"^si|si\d+|si-"), topProdukte!AV2, "NO"))`

Now I try to add an AND NOT condition and fail on something. I try it with negative lookahead

`=ArrayFormula(if( REGEXMATCH(topProdukte!AV2,"^(?!sia)si|si\d+|si-"), topProdukte!AV2, "NO"))` as adviced in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3194881/1992004 - but get an error #REF, not valid regex.

Finally I need to match strings containing `^si|si\d+|si-`, but not containing `*sia*`.

Comment: Do you mean you do not want to match string that start with `sia`? Then, you'd be able to use `^si(?:[^a]|$)|si\d+|si-`. Else, if `sia` anywhere in the string signals failure, you can't add it to this regex, add a separate check.

Comment: could you say how to add a separate check in the same formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- Makes sure all your regexps match whole string since it is a requirement coming from `REGEXMATCH`
- Add a separate statement checking if `sia` is not present in the string.

So, a possible solution is

```js
=ArrayFormula(if( AND(NOT(REGEXMATCH(topProdukte!AV2, ".*sia.*")), REGEXMATCH(topProdukte!AV2,"^si.*|.*si\d.*|.*si-.*")), topProdukte!AV2, "NO"))
```

Here,

- `AND(...,...)` requires both conditions to pass / return true
- `NOT(REGEXMATCH(topProdukte!AV2, ".*sia.*"))`  - makes sure the string does `NOT` contain `sia` (note the `.*` on both ends make sure the whole string is consumed)
- `REGEXMATCH(topProdukte!AV2,"^si.*|.*si\d.*|.*si-.*")` - the part you already have: it matches `si` at the start of string, `si`+digit or `si-` anywhere in the string.